# How can I get the list of Microsoft.Web/sites/functions through Azure Bicep?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-api-management, azure-bicep

I am trying to get all the functions from Microsoft.Web/sites/functions to add them into Azure API Management.

something like this

```http
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{name}/functions?api-version=2022-03-01
```

checkout https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/web-apps/list-functions for docs.

I want to do the same () thing through bicep.

I found out there is a list property of bicep which can help to list the data. I saw the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/bicep-functions-resource)
[image]
but unable to find the something like list functions.

What I want to do is is to get all the @HttpTriggers mapping (microsoft.web/sites/functions) of the Function App through bicep and add them to API Management. Can anybody help with this?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do it directly in ARM / Bicep, but you can use a script deployment as part of template. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/deployment-script-bicep. Doing this would allow get the details from the azure functions and return the values to the ARM / Bicep template.